# How to parse a string matching a pattern but skipping another in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have some problems with the regular expression module of python and its correct usage.

Let us assume to have the following string:

```
string = """
---start_skip
---start_keep1
some data
---end_keep
---end_skip

---start_keep2
some other data
---end_keep
""""
```

I can parse the "keep" data by simply

```
import re
keep_re = re.compile(r"---start_keep(.*?)---end_keep",re.DOTALL)
for match in re.finditer(keep_re,string):
  data = match.group()
```

However I don't know ho to skip all `"---start_keep/---end_keep"` substrings that are contained into `"---start_skip/---end_skip"` tags. In fact, my snippet matches also the `"---start_keep1/--end_keep"` block that in my intention should be "protected" by the `"---start_skip/---end_skip"` tags.

Can someone help me?

EDIT:

In my production problem I have more issues:

1. the skip regex (that changes at runtime) has not a fixed lenght; the negative match cannot be used;
2. the skip regex is enclosed into a capturing group because in other context it is not a skip regex, instead it is a keep one!

An example closer to the production problem is the following:

```
import re
keep_re = re.compile(r"(?P<keep>---start_keep(?P<data>.*?)---end_keep)",re.DOTALL)
skip_re = re.compile(r"(?P<skip>[`]{3}.*?[`]{3})",re.DOTALL)
```

and the test string should like:

````
string = """
---start_keepThis data
is not protected and can be "kept" (managed, substituted,...)
---end_keep

```
---start_keepEven if this data are inside a keep regex
they should be "protected" by the "```" tags...
---end_keep
```
````

If I use the "|" operator as suggested I face with the capturing skip_re. Presently I am trying to make it not capturing with "?:", but I have no success :-(

To be more clear, the first thing I would like to do is to substitute all "keep" data that are not protected by a skip tags.

**VERY DIRTY SOLUTION:**

Dear all,

my current production solution is very dirty, thus I like to show it in order to read your critics.

I write the following small class method:

```
def strip(self,source):
  """Method for striping raw data from source.

  Parameters
  ----------
  source : str
    string (as single stream) containing the source

  Returns
  -------
  str
    source without the raw data
  """
  if self.skip:
    strip_source = source
    pattern = '|'.join([ skip.pattern for skip in self.skip ])
    regex = re.compile(pattern+r"|(?P<strip>"+self.regex.pattern+r")",re.DOTALL)
    matches = []
    for match in re.finditer(regex,strip_source):
      if match.group('strip'):
        matches.append([match.start(),match.end()])
    if len(matches)>0:
      strip = ''
      for mtc,match in enumerate(matches):
        if mtc == 0:
          start = 0
        else:
          start = matches[mtc-1][1]+1
        if match[0]!=start:
          strip += strip_source[start:match[0]-1]
      if matches[-1][1]<len(strip_source):
        strip += strip_source[matches[-1][1]+1:]
      strip_source = strip
  else:
    strip_source = re.sub(self.regex,'',source)
  return strip_source.strip()
```

where for each match of the "skip|keep" regex I check if "keep" (in the method it is named "strip" because it is a strip method...) is the one matched and, in case, I manage it (in this case I strip it out). I have to firstly store the start/end matches character to strip they out in the second passage... Note that the "skip|keep" regex is "complex" because I can have a list of "skip" containers.

Any suggestions are welcome, in any case thank you for your help!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Did you try using `match.group(1)` instead of `match.group()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
---start_skip.*?---end_skip|---start_keep\d+(.*?)---end_keep
```

Try this.This will get you the parts required.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/54

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but what I want is to match "some other data" without match "some data"

Comment: @szaghi do not forget to mark the answer correct if it satisfies your xpecations :)

Comment: thank you very much, indeed I do not need to skip the number after ---start_keep, thus I can remove the "\d+" before the matching group.

Comment: however can I ask you some more explanation? the "|" operator do the magic, how it works in this case? It should be the "or" operator, thus I suppose that it matches also "some data" but it works...

Comment: maybe the magic consists in the "non matching group" of the first alternative while the second has a matching group?

Comment: @szaghi the first match before `|` takes all the string you want to skip...then from the left over the sceond part grabs the part you want

Comment: @szaghi basically after string matches first part before `|` it will not match second part.So start_skip is missed and then second part is matched

Comment: Yes, I guess... my actual problem fits better with your approach. Thank you very much.

Comment: because in other parts of the code what is now a "skip" block can become a "keep" one and viceversa. I have found a "dirty" solution that actually works only for stripping out the "keep" blocks that are not protected by a skip tags, however I guess that a more regex solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind to match from  `start-keep` which isn't immediately preceded by `start_skip`,

```
(?<!---start_skip\n)---start_keep\d+\n.*?---end_keep
```

Use a capturing group to capture the inbetween characters.

```
(?<!---start_skip\n)---start_keep\d+\n(.*?)---end_keep
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/55)

Comment: Your are right, the negative look is the first solution I have tried but I have not do it well... Your solution is very clear, thank you very much!

Comment: @szaghi it will not work in this case http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/56 neither this http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/57

Comment: do not worry, in my regex I do not check for newline. Thanks again

Comment: @szaghi even a space after it will break this pattern

Comment: Sure I know, your regex is perferct for the example I have posted where the tags are separated by \n. Indeed, my production problem is more complex than the one I have posted, thus I cannot use your approach at all, but it is nice for what I have posted and I learn a lot from it. Presently I have to use the "|" operator because my actual skip regex has not a fixed dimension thus I cannot use negative lookbehind

Comment: @AvinashRaj i wanted him to choose the correct answer so that he desnt fall into trouble later

Comment: @sza `Indeed, my production problem is more complex than the one I have posted, thus I cannot use your approach at all`. Could you post an example?

Comment: I have edited the original question introducing a more production-close example...

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

My solution for this is a bit long:

```
(?m)^(?:---start_skip\n(?:(?!---end_skip\n)[^\n]*\n)*---end_skip|(?!---start_keep)[^\n]*\n)*---start_keep[^\n]*\n((?:(?!---end_keep)[^\n]*\n)*)---end_keep
```

**Before using this, please read the Assumptions section.**

Though it can correctly pick out the matches from such test case:

```
data
---start_skip

data

---start_keep1
some data

---end_keep

more data
---end_skip

whoknows

---start_keep2
sdff
some other data
---end_keep

less data

---start_keep2

---end_keep
---start_keep2
---end_keep
---start_skip
dsfsdf
---start_keep
---end_keep
dsfdsf

---start_keep


---end_keep

---end_skip

sdfsdf

---start_keep2

werewrewrewrewrewrwewrew,,[p.[

sdfdsf

wer;[we;

---end_keep
```

[**Demo on regex101**](http://regex101.com/r/sR7mT4/2)

### Assumptions

1. Assuming previous sections (keep or skip) have closed when you encounter `---start-skip`, everything between `---start_skip` and nearest `---end_skip` are ignored. Consequently, no nested section.
2. Assuming previous sections (keep or skip) have closed when you encounter `---start-keep`, everything between `---start_keep` and nearest `---end_keep` are treated as text to be kept. Consequently, no nested section.
3. The behavior is undefined when a start tag is found but the corresponding end tag is not found.

   An example where behavior is undefined:

   ```
   ---start_skip
   ---start_keep
   something
   ---end_keep
   ```
4. If the input has many `---start_keep` in a row without any `---end_keep`, the regex is going to have poor performance, even with the small addition of `(?m)^`.

### Explanation

```
(?m)^                              # Start matching from beginning of a line
(?:
  ---start_skip\n                  # Match skip section
  (?:(?!---end_skip\n)[^\n]*\n)*   # Take all lines in between skip section
  ---end_skip
  |
  (?!---start_keep)[^\n]*\n        # Not valid skip section. Match text until start_keep
)*                                 # Can be many skip sections and text until keep section
---start_keep[^\n]*\n              # Match keep section
((?:(?!---end_keep)[^\n]*\n)*)     # Capture text in between keep section
---end_keep
```

The `(?m)^` part is used to reduce unnecessary work when not encountering any keep section at the end of the data, and to also ignore the section tags in middle of a line.

Comment: Your contribution is very interesting. However I have a question: why not use a simple .*? for the content of "---start_skip/---end_skip"? I have no necessity to track lines break, my string is a stream blob...

Comment: @szaghi: It's a little bit stronger in a sense that there is no way a valid `---end-skip` tag can appear as some line in the middle. A simple `.*?` allows `---end-skip` to appear in the middle if it backtracks. I also assume that the tags are only valid if it is at the beginning of a line - that's the reason for all the complexity. Since you are not giving all the information, I have to make the assumption to write some regex.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. Indeed I do not request that the tags are valid only if they are at the beginning of a line. Anyhow your contribution has been helpfull